# What is the pythonic way to test whether two objects are the same, not just equal

Tags: python, pointers, comparison-operators

My solution has been to make the object's address into a string, which should always be unique.

Below is a case where it works both ways, comparing the objects and comparing the values of `str(object_a)` and `str(object_b)`.

```
>>> class Thing:
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         self.x = 0
>>>         return
>>>
>>> a = Thing()
>>> b = a
>>> b == a
True
>>> a_string = str(a)
>>> b_string = str(b)
>>> a_string
<__main__.Thing instance at 0x16c0098>
>>> b_string
<__main__.Thing instance at 0x16c0098>
>>> a_string == b_string
True
```

What is the pythonic way?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem is by giving an example of output that is not what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple sure-fire way to check for equality is `==`:

```
a == b
```

The simple sure-fire way to check to see if they have the same identity is `is`:

```
a is b
```

The 2nd way (`is`) performs the same check that you intend `str(a)==str(b)` to perform.

Answer (score 1):

With your code you aren't comparing two objects in a faster way, but just asking if your *variables* points to the same object, which is quite different.

Anyway, the pythonic way to do it is not casting pointers to string, but using operator "is":

```
>>> a is b
True
>>> b is A
True
```